# How can I represent all combinations of a word, such that the word keeps atleast one letter at its original place?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I devised a formula for this problem: $26^{length-1}*length-1$. This formula satisfies its intended result with length being one, for example. But when I use length of two, it misses the result by 1 (e.g. $26^{1}*2 = 52$, intended result being 51 combinations, because original combinations is counted twice).

For an example, we have a word: $abc$. We use the formula, so the result is $26^{2}*3 = 2028$. But $abc$ doesn't have that many combinations ($aac → zzc, aba → zbz, aaa → azz$) such that it keeps one original letter from itself, it has $1951$ combinations.

I would like to ask, where could I have gone wrong with this formula?

Comment: Can you explain / show your work for how you calculated 51 and 1951? Based on what I interpret your question as, my answer would have been $ l \times 25^{l-1}$.

Comment: Math mode isn't intended for italicizing text; as you can see here, it yields the wrong spacing for that. Usually text is italicized by enclosing it in asterisks. If you want to italicize text within math mode, you can use `\mathit{...}`. In the present case, there doesn't seem to be a need to italicize the text; in that case you can use `\text{...}` to include roman text in math mode.

Comment: Thanks, just a beginner with latex. Will come in handy!

Comment: [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/)'s a tutorial and reference for typesetting math on this site.

Comment: @Calvin Lin I tried to use the formula, but it doesn't work. It is still off, $1875$ vs $1951$.

Comment: Can you clarify "intended result being 51 combinations, because original combinations is counted twice"? Specifically, shouldn't the original combination not be included, since it keeps both letters in its original space? After that, please write out how you're calculating 1951 for 3 letters.

Comment: I'm calculating the 1951 via $26^{3} - 25^{3}$. It's counting the original combination (e.g. *ab*, when I use the equation $26^{1} * 2 = 52$, it gives the wrong result of 52, when it should be 51).

Comment: @CalvinLin I mean, it's counting the original combination two times when the length is 2, but only once when the length is 1.

Comment: Do you agree that $26^l - 25^l$ is the number of combinations with at least 1 match to the original combination? You're looking for "exactly 1 match" right?

Comment: I'm looking for all the combinations of a word, such that the word keeps only one letter at its original place. There is 1 match in the combinations if they calculated correctly.

Comment: I agree that it's number of combinations with at least 1 match. But it should be 1 match to the original combination. The point of formula I'm devising is to represent all combinations of a word, such that the word (*abc*) keeps atleast one letter at its original place(*aac, abc, adc..; aba, abb, abc..; aaa, aab, aac*). Oh, I just realized I made a mistake. I meant to keep **atleast** two letters at its original place.

Comment: @CalvinLin Please revise the question once again as I made a mistake